# Rebuild DataFrame without empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to rebuild DataFrame in python without empty cells.
I looks like this: [image]

And i would like it to look something like this:
[image]

I have tried using fillna() and notnull() but they all remove empty rows or columns.
Is there a function to rebuild this or simply remove empty cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in a row-by-row iterative process. Each row simply needs to "float" its contents as far left as it can, pushing all empty values to the right. To do this, I write a utility method:

```py
def float_left(row):
    vals = row.values.copy()
    floated = []
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        if not np.isnan(vals[i]):
            floated.append(vals[i])
    while len(floated) < len(vals):
        floated.append(np.nan)
    row = floated.copy()
    return row
```

Now I can repeatedly apply this method to each row of the table, which I do using `pandas` builtin `apply` method:

```py
df = df.apply(float_left, axis=1)
```

The result of this should have all entries floated left as you wanted. If not, please let me know!

Comment: This is very advanced for me so I apologise if I can't explain myself very clearly. I have tried this code (simply put into my script) and get this error:

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: What datatype is your data? If all strings, you could try using the if condition `if len(vals[i]) > 0` instead of `if not np.isnan(vals[i])`